# grouped scatterhist in subplot in matlab

Tags: matlab

I am trying to make subplots using the `grouped scatterhist` function in matlab.

```
subplot(2,2,1)
scatterhist(x,y,'Group',factor)
subplot(2,2,2)
scatterhist(x,y,'Group',factor)
```

This makes one normal sized plot of the second subplot. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`scatterhist`  doesn't interact well with `subplot`, so you have to find ways around that.

Here is a way of doing it with `uipanel`.

```
% create two separate figures with the two scatterplots in
h1 = figure
scatterhist(x,y,'Group',factor)
h2 = figure
scatterhist(x,y,'Group',factor)

% create third figure split into two uipanels
h3 = figure
u1 = uipanel('position',[0,0,0.5,1]);
u2 = uipanel('position',[0.5,0,0.5,1);

% get all children from each figure and move to the uipanels
set(get(h1,'Children'),'parent',u1);
set(get(h2,'Children'),'parent',u2);

%close unneeded figures
close(h1,h2)
```

If you wanted to do a lot of these, you might want to create a function that works out the right `position` values depending on how many subplots you want in the figure.